# postgres how to revoke set command

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible for a user to not be able to run set commands to change work_mem etc? Certain users are setting work_mem and parallel sessions to high values impacting other sessions, would like to disable/revoke set from users, please let me know.

Comment: No, you cannot disallow SET, or otherwise (there are other ways) prevent per-session settings from being changed. Clients are assumed to be trusted.

Comment: Thanks. by "there are other ways" - do you mean there are non-straight forward ways to implement restriction?

Comment: No, I mean there are other ways besides `SET` of changing `work_mem`, etc. Direct UPDATEs to pg_settings will apply if the row updated is for a session-local variable, as well as a built-in [set_config()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this cannot be done. For that reason, don't give untrusted users the opportunity to run arbitrary SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a extension that allows to customize SET statements:
https://github.com/pierreforstmann/pg_set_level

Note that it only works for SET statement and does not take set_config() function into account.

Comment: This is cool, but unfortunately I am on RDS Aurora Postgres and this is not one of the supported extensions.